# C list of pointers (double pointers)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to make a list of pointers to a structure called "thread". Here is my attempt:

```
//kmalloc is my malloc, don't worry
struct thread **process0 = kmalloc(sizeof(struct *thread));
```

//^ This line is giving me a parse error

And basically I want `process0[0]` to be a pointer to a thread,
`process0[1]` to be a pointer to another thread, 
`process0[2]` to be a pointer to yet another thread, 
etc.

Later I may want to access one of the thread's "addrspace" member (a pointer to an `addrspace` structure) along the following:

```
struct addrspace *test = process0[i][j]->addrspace;
```

Where I'm thinking `proccess0[i]` is a particular list of thread pointers, and `process0[i][j]` is a particular thread pointer from the particular list of thread pointers... Then I'd want to access one of its members via the `->` operator.

I've always sucked at pointer arithmetic stuff and would like to get things cleared up. Thank you very much.

Comment: process0[i][j] would be of type struct thread, so you would use the . not the -> accessor

Comment: Oh. I was getting a parse error on the first line of code I put up for the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datatype that you want is "pointer to struct thread", or:

```
struct thread **process0 = kmalloc(sizeof(struct thread *));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct thread **process0 = kmalloc(sizeof(struct * thread)*NUM_THREADS*NUM_PROCESSES_IN_EACH_THREAD); //kmalloc is my malloc, don't worry
```

Before you were only allocating like one pointer, if I read it right.  Does this help at all?